# Integrating problem using interface

Tags: functions, fourier-analysis, interface

lately I tried to develop an interface that will plot the furier sum of a given function up to a given number of terms.

The code is here:

```
isEven[f_] := SameQ[f[t], f[(-t)]]
a[n_, f_] := If[isEven[f], Integrate[f[y]*Cos[n y], {y, -Pi, Pi}], 0]
b[n_, f_] := If[isEven[f], 0, Integrate[f[y]*Sin[n y], {y, -Pi, Pi}]]
fourier[f_, m_] := Sum[a[n, f]*Cos[n x] + b[n, f]*Sin[n x], {n, 1, m}]

Interpretation[
 {g = x^2, min = 0, max = 2 Pi, sum = 5},
 Panel[
    Grid[{{Style["Furier Series", Bold], SpanFromLeft},
            {"Function:", InputField[Dynamic[g]]},
            {"Min:", InputField[Dynamic[min]]},
            {"Max:", InputField[Dynamic[max]]},
            {"Sum:", InputField[Dynamic[sum]]}}]
  ],
 Plot[Evaluate[fourier[g[x], sum]], {x, min, max}]]
```

The first part specifies the functions I would need, and the second part is an inteface to use the tool.

When i run the code, a keep getting these errors:

[image]

And then gives me an empty plot.

Does anyone here know what is the problem?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: First of all, please revise your theory about Fourier Analysis. In a hurry, you integrate wrt `y` and your function is defined as dependent on `x`...

Answer (score 1):

After some corrections, and removing some parts not needed (the code is equally fast), I suggest this (with `NIntegrate` the code goes faster):

```
a[n_, f_] := 1/\[Pi] Integrate[f*Cos[n x], {x, -Pi, Pi}];
b[n_, f_] := 1/\[Pi] Integrate[f*Sin[n x], {x, -Pi, Pi}];
fourier[f_, m_] := 1/(2 \[Pi]) Integrate[f, {x, -Pi, Pi}] + 
                   Sum[a[n, f]*Cos[n x] + b[n, f]*Sin[n x], {n, 1, m}];

Interpretation[{g = x^2, min = -Pi, max = Pi, sum = 5}, 
 Panel[Grid[{{Style["Fourier Series", Bold], 
 SpanFromLeft}, {"Function:", InputField[Dynamic[g]]}, {"Min:", 
 InputField[Dynamic[min]]}, {"Max:", 
 InputField[Dynamic[max]]}, {"Sum:", InputField[Dynamic[sum]]}}]],
 Plot[{g, Evaluate[fourier[g, sum]]}, {x, min, max}, 
 PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, PlotLegends -> {"f(x)", "Fourier Approx."}]]
```

[image]

[image]